# Android Disable SSL Pinning on OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp

I need to disable SSL Pinning to do some security tests on my App using a proxy. Is there an easy way to disable this programmatically using OkHttp?

Every solution I found online is modifying the smali bytecodes inside the apk.

That's my client builder:

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory())
.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
        return true;
    }
}).connectTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.readTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.writeTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();
```

Comment: Hi @Victor - have you got anything for this? I am also looking for similar kind of solution.

Comment: @MohammadMisbah I think OkHttp3 have the SSL Pinning disabled by default